# Как работает return в функциях JS?

Tags: javascript, функции, return

```
function append(massive, b) {
    return massive.push(b)
}

let massiveOne = new Array()
let massiveTwo= new Array()

massiveTwo = append(massiveOne, "something")
```

Почему в этом случае `massiveTwo` не станет `massiveOne` уже с еще одним элементом, а `massiveOne` внезапно получит элемент?
Разве функция не должна возвратить мне данные не вмешиваясь в общее пространство?

Comment: Не понятно, при чем тут функция, она вообще не вызывается. А `push()` после срабатывания возвращает новую длину массива (т.е. число 1), оно и записывается в переменную massiveTwo

Comment: Прошу прощения... Но почему функция возвращает длину массива, даже если я не запрашивал ее?

Comment: Это [описанное поведение функции](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) и с этим всегда надо сверяться: какие-то функции меняют исходный массив, какие-то возвращают новый не меняя старого, а какие-то могут иметь неожиданное для вас поведение)

Comment: Запрашивали) push так устроен, добавляет элемент в массив и возвращает его длину. `function append(massive, b) { massive.push(b); return massive; }` — так будет возвращать ссылку на массив...

Comment: Спасибо! И все-таки... весьма странные у JS причуды.